# How to use DPSSessionService through CQ API

Tags: java, aem, adobe-dps

I would like to use the CQ API call to delete a folio in the folio producer.  I saw the http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/media/publishing/dps/fp/DPSSessionService.html can create a session.
Once the session is created, I could use http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/media/publishing/dps/fp/DPSFolioProducerService.html to delete a folio with the folioId.
I don't know how I can implement this interface to make this work.  I tried to @Reference
   private DPSSessionService dpssession;

However, this doesn't gets my process deployed to my workflow.  I'm not sure how I can get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get your service through the context of your OSGi bundle.

You could try something like this (not tested though):

```
BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference dpsFolioProducerServiceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(DPSFolioProducerService.class);
DPSFolioProducerService yourDPSFolioProducerService = (DPSFolioProducerService) bundleContext.getService(dpsFolioProducerServiceReference );
```

You could use this for example in your servlet.

1. Get the bundle context
2. Construct a reference to your service
3. Get the service using your reference

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work:

```
@Reference
private DPSSessionService sessionService;
private DPSSession dpsSession = null;
private DPSFolioProducerService folioProducer; 

 try {
    dpsSession = sessionService.createSession("username", "password");
     folioProducer = dpsSession.adaptTo(DPSFolioProducerService.class);
     folioProducer.deleteFolio(folioId);
      sessionService.deleteSession(dpsSession);
   } catch (DPSSessionServiceException ex) {
       log.error("Failed setup", ex);
   } catch (DPSFolioProducerServiceException e) {
      log.error("Delete Folio failed", e);
    }
```